# $.each function is not iterating

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am working with a relatively complex JSON structure and am unable to iterate through it via the $.each() function. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the weird 2-dimensional array I am passing through in the value section of the normal array (hope that made sense). I am new to Ajax and JSON so just need some guidance on the best way to handle JSON when it is returned via an AJAX Call. Thanks!

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'model.php',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
         encode : true 
        }).done(function(data){
        
                        var i = 0;
                      
                        for(var k in data){ 
                            window.alert(k);  
                        }   //this works         
            
                      $.each(data, function(key, value){ //however this does not display anything
                         
                          window.alert("should be outputted");
                          window.alert("key" + key + "value" + value[i]['email']);
                          i++;
                          
                      });
                  });
```

JSON I am using:

```
{"bodge.com":[{"email":"mgbbuqc@bodge.com","orders":"2","value":"19.67"},{"email":"vswmdkqtb@bodge.com","orders":"5","value":"21.89"},{"email":"fwzqfjma@bodge.com","orders":"3","value":"13.71"},{"email":"rwsofs@bodge.com","orders":"7","value":"6.49"},{"email":"vfr@bodge.com","orders":"3","value":"24.36"},{"email":"wcs@bodge.com","orders":"3","value":"11.26"},{"email":"oqmsboag@bodge.com","orders":"3","value":"5.36"},{"email":"wdvm@bodge.com","orders":"6","value":"18.21"},{"email":"xubumenme@bodge.com","orders":"1","value":"10.24"},{"email":"pleqlwpha@bodge.com","orders":"2","value":"6.59"},{"email":"dqhdcnvw@bodge.com","orders":"10","value":"7.85"},{"email":"gyxymze@bodge.com","orders":"1","value":"15.51"},{"email":"otbbqcw@bodge.com","orders":"2","value":"7.92"},{"email":"afspqpq@bodge.com","orders":"3","value":"13.22"},{"email":"fwovyddw@bodge.com","orders":"4","value":"23.14"},{"email":"urczmgy@bodge.com","orders":"7","value":"15.17"},{"email":"hkgccna@bodge.com","orders":"4","value":"17.62"},{"email":"hlrnunyf@bodge.com","orders":"4","value":"22.03"},{"email":"gafoubu@bodge.com","orders":"10","value":"16.71"},{"email":"muwfjqs@bodge.com","orders":"4","value":"6.09"},{"email":"ddjeqvu@bodge.com","orders":"1","value":"23.88"},{"email":"jbq@bodge.com","orders":"8","value":"5.37"}],"bodge.com ":[{"email":"uytdlcgd@bodge.com ","orders":" 9 ","value":" 21.22"}]}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet sorry I should've made myself more clear, the error is that the $.each function is not displaying anything and I want to know how to properly iterate through my results. No error per se, just not the output I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has (at least) two levels:

1. an object with keys (`"bodge.com", "bodge.com "`), and
2. each key holds an array of objects

   ```
   {
       "bodge.com": [
           {"email":"mgbbuqc@bodge.com","orders":"2","value":"19.67"},
           {"email":"vswmdkqtb@bodge.com","orders":"5","value":"21.89"},
           ...
           {"email":"ddjeqvu@bodge.com","orders":"1","value":"23.88"},
           {"email":"jbq@bodge.com","orders":"8","value":"5.37"}
       ],
       "bodge.com ": [
           {"email":"uytdlcgd@bodge.com ","orders":" 9 ","value":" 21.22"}
       ]
   }
   ```

In order to iterate through the structure, you will need at least two levels of iteration:

```
$.each(data, function(domain, objects) {
    console.log(domain); // will output "bodge.com" or "bodge.com "
    $.each(objects, function(index, x) {
        console.log(x.email);
        console.log(x.orders);
        console.log(x.value);
        console.log(index); // will output the 0-based position of x within the array
    });
});
```

Note that you are using `$.each` for two different kinds of iteration: first over the keys and values of an object, then over the items in an array.

As an alternative, use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of an object's keys, and the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(domain) {
    console.log(domain); // will output "bodge.com" or "bodge.com "
    data[domain].forEach(function(x, index) {
        console.log(x.email);
        console.log(x.orders);
        console.log(x.value);
        console.log(index); // will output the 0-based position of x within the array
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be bypassing data['bodge.com'] into the each function rather that simply data.

Comment: there are two items, "bodge.com" and "bodge.com " with space, but looks like this is the error

Comment: So you probably need multiple loops, or you need to restructure your API response (if that's an option)

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately bodge.com is simply and example of several domains of output I could receive, if I use .com as my input for the AJAX request it will return all the different domains. And yes @Diego it is an error, just me forgetting to remove the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'model.php',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
     encode : true 
    }).done(function(data){

var list = JSON.parse(data);     

                  $.each(list, function(i){
                     alert(list[i].your_filed);
                  });            
});
```

Comment: Could you clarify something for me? The fact that I declared dataType:'json' would do JSON.parse(data) for me anyway right? But because of my json data this wouldn't work anyway would it? Would it not just display the whole array? I am not trying to be critical btw, I am just trying to understand this. Thanks for the response

Comment: Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)   If my answer work for you please correct it :)